# list all movies with information about screen resoulion

Tags: command-line, filenames, movieclip

I am uploading many files to server where I need to enter frames resolution - it's much inconvenient to do it "manually" - open each file and then check their properties.
I would like to get a *list of all movie files* names (in .mpg and .swf format) with *information about their screen resolution* from windows command line (or PowerShell, or Linux console). How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Look at midentify (mplayer tools); The output is not pretty but can easily be parsed so you can present it in the desired format

***note**: midentify is a wrapper around `mplayer -identify` IIRC*